# Is there an idiom or proverb that implies simplicity is good?

Tags: idiom-request, proverbs

Is there an idiom or proverb that implies simplicity is good? I was trying to find some idioms or proverbs that implied simplicity is good, and I was looking for some idioms or proverbs that implied that simplicity in general is good, and not simplicity in a particular case. I find it surprising that I ended up empty-ended after some research.

Comment: There's always, "Less is more." It's not exactly an idiom, but a quote, from (many think) architect Mies van der Rohe. (But https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/less-is-more seems to dispute that idea.) Anyway, it's pretty well known, and it does support the value of simplicity, but maybe not as forcefully or specifically as you are looking for.

Comment: https://www.habitsforwellbeing.com/20-inspirational-quotes-on-simplicity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When the solution is simple, God is answering."
"Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler"
"The definition of genius is taking the complex and making it simple."
"If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough."
"Out of clutter, find simplicity"
- Albert Einstein

"Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication."
- Leonardo da Vinci